# How long does it take to update a version of Google Spreadsheet Scripts add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I've found an important bug on my Google Spreadsheet Add-on. I pushed the new version yesterday and 24 hours later is still not updated. I have clients angry with this bug that is already solved, but pending on someone to be updated.

Last time, my updates takes minutes to perform it, but now it's taking too long.

What can I do?

This is the store link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/route-optimizer-smartmonk/ebjgghodfhffloccipkmahndnpemnjoj?authuser=0

Thanks

Comment: You should post this question to the [Developing Add-ons for GSuite community](https://plus.google.com/communities/117193953428311185494)  Your question is "off-topic."  It's not a programming question or a question about the code editor.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience I've found that it varies.

Add-ons are published to all regions world-wide by default. That means an update has to propagate to servers world over. I can't say definitively that this will work but if you reduce the number of regions where your add-on is available you might get better update times.

If you have analytics on add-on usage and can effectively pinpoint which regions don't use your add-on, then I would recommend that you disable those regions the next time you deploy your add-on.